# SFMC HTML UL Lists Adding Extra Bullet

Tags: html, html-lists, nested-lists, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have an extra bullet showing up after my UL ends.

```html
<ul> 
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text
    <ul>
      <li>Text</li>
      <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried several solutions that have not resolved the issue.

Comment: The result looks as expected in my browser.  Are you sure this is the exact markup used?  Are you sure there is *no* CSS styling being applied?

Comment: David - there is styling in the table that this is enclosed in but there is no CSS that styles lists specifically

Comment: Without a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, I don't see how anybody can help.  The code shown is working as expected.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Code snippet works as intended

Answer (score 0):

As checked, this code is working as expected in my instance.
Please check if you have other codes being linked in your email content.

```
<ul> 
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text
    <ul>
      <li>Text</li>
      <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

5 "Text" value as in "Bold Circle Bullet"
2 "Text" value as in "Empty Circle Bullet"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the extra bullet you're seeing after your `<ul>` ends is caused by a CSS styling issue. Specifically, if your `<ul>` element has a `display: list-item;` or `display: inherit;` style, it may cause an extra bullet to appear.

One way to fix this issue is to add a style to your CSS that sets the display property of all `<ul>` elements to **block**.

For example:

```
ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Also, you can add a class if you want to apply it to only a specific `<ul>` element.

For example:

```
ul.remove-duplicated-circle {
  display: block;
}
```

And your list would be as following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text
        <ul class="remove-duplicated-circle">
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This should remove the extra bullet that's appearing after your `<ul>` ends. If this doesn't solve the problem, you may need to provide more information about your **CSS** and **HTML** code.